# Reference on nets and filters for non-topologists

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request

From what I've read, a good few proofs in functional analysis can be simplified by taking advantage of a latent property of nets or filters (such as the proof that a closed subspace of a reflexive Banach space is reflexive: you simply apply the fact that a space is compact iff every net has a convergent subnet [alternatively, every filter has a convergent refinement] along with the fact that a Banach space is reflexive iff the unit closed ball is compact in the weak topology). However, I don't have much of a topology background, and although my intention is to rectify that at some point, I'd love to have a reference for some of the specific uses of nets and filters in analysis. Does anybody have a suggestion for some relevant reading? Thanks!

Comment: In answer to Gerald A. Edgar's 17 April 2000 sci.math post asking *I am looking for some references dealing with nets (generalized sequences) used in analysis (as opposed to used in general topology*, I posted some references [here](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=237947). I don't have time right now to reformat this for a stackexchange answer, however. (I notice the URL's I posted are no longer there. If you want them, try google's sci.math archive.)

Comment: Also, I think Albert Wilansky's book [**Functional Analysis**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B000MVV5NS) makes use of nets. I don't think I mentioned this book in my 2000 sci.math post.